# Over-shadowing label when pre-populating value to form

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I'm using Materialized CSS and it works very well for me. However when I added more dynamic behaviour to my app, for example when I'm pre-populating form with values and appending them to the layout, here is the photo of that:

[image]

That happens only when I preset the value to form on/prior to page load (because my form html is generated by server side).

However if I were to click into the quantity field then quantity would go back to its place and it would stay there.

[image]

How do I make it so that it stays up even when I pre-populate the form value? Is there a class I need to add to it (label or input) or JavaScript or something that I can put out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pre-fill text inputs, use `Materialize.updateTextField();` as the [docs](http://materializecss.com/forms.html) says

[image]

Comment: badass man! I was looking for it in the docs couldn't find it, appreciate it!